# Cannot use custom select box using backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, windows-phone-8

Am developing windows phone app with backbone.js using phonegap. When i try to use a custom select box like this image.[image: Custom selectbox] it always shows the default select box like this [image: Default SelectBox]

Why it is not displaying the custom select box?

**My Code**

HTML:

```
 <select class="custom-select custom-select-smaller no-border" id="lang-select">
```

CSS:

```
.custom-select {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
 color: #6b6b6b;
 height: 38px;
 font-size: 11px;
 line-height: 38px;
 padding: 0 6px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100% !important;
 display: block !important;
}
.custom-select.custom-select-smaller {
height: 34px;
line-height: 34px;
}
.custom-select.custom-select-smaller:after {
top: 14px;
}
#lang-select{
 z-index:~1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling a  element is always tricky and not reliable.

You may wanna add the following styles to get it to work in webkit & firefox

```
-webkit-appearance: initial;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
```

But it's not possible (so far as I know) to make it work in IE. If you wanna get consistent results, try to use ul+li with hidden  tags.

or just use a plugin like http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/

Comment: Tried with both the source and plugin but not working for me. Along with this am getting a background color as green (which is default in windows phone) once i select an item in select box

Comment: your code doesn't include the styles for the down arrow. you should be able to get an empty box after applying my css. (well, again, in chrome and firefox only). in this case you may wanna create another element with the style you want instead of trying to style the native select.